# How to get the API link that contains the bestseller badges by python?

Tags: python, api, scrapy, web-crawler, badge

I am having a task to get the data of the bestseller badges in this link https://www.real.de/item/search/?search_value=lattenrost&valueKey_search_value= .
I tried to find the API link in the Web Developer Tool (XHR tab) however still havent managed to find it yet.
Do you know where can i get the link or anyway to get the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all built-in into the page source code.
See **hm.initialSearchData** variable in a script tag.

---

Use regexps to extract data you need.

```
import re
import json

resp = your response text

json_text = re.findall('hm.initialSearchData = (.+?)</script>', resp)
data = json.loads(json_text[0])
```